# Forgotten Password to be unmasked or revealed

Tags: internet-explorer, passwords

I launch IE, type 192.168.1.1. It comes up with a screen asking for user name and password.

I type the user name and password (I know the password for this screen).

I click on Login.

I see Huwaei (my modem) splash screen with the following options - 
Home, Setup, Advanced, Tools and Status.

I choose Setup and select PVC0.

Then you have got the PPP Settings displayed. This has the username, password ( I do NOT know this password) and few other fields. I would like to know this password.

I looked up in Google and found a software called [Password Unmask 2.0](http://www.alpinesnow.com/pwu.shtml).

I installed it and it is revealing the password of Windows based Applications, but not the one that is listed in Internet Explorer.

Can someone please help. Thanks in advance.

PS: I agree that forgetting passwords is not a very nice thing to do!

Comment: Reset your wireless modem and start afresh using the default password

Comment: Aha, that edit changes things a bit. That password might in fact be bogus, *if* your provider has other means of identifying who you are. (Like my provider does not require any password, as it knows exactly from which telephone wire I connect, and thus uses one dummy password for every subscriber.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There're are [many bookmarklets](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22reveal+password%22+bookmarklet) on the net that get the password using some JavaScript. I cannot test with Internet Explorer, but just one out of many: [Show, Reveal, View or See Hidden Password Field Text](http://thepcsecurity.com/show-reveal-view-or-see-hidden-password-field-text/).

Comment: Thanks Arjan. This finally did the trick! I have now got back my password!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the freeware [IE PassView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/internet_explorer_password.html).

> IE PassView is a small password management utility that reveals the passwords stored by Internet Explorer Web browser, and allows you to delete passwords that you don't need anymore. **It supports all versions of Internet Explorer, from version 4.0 and up to 8.0**.
>   For each password that is stored by Internet Explorer, the following information is displayed: Web address, Password Type (AutoComplete, Password-Protected Web Site, or FTP), Storage Location (Registry, Credentials File, or Protected Storage), and the user name/password pair. You can select one or more items from the passwords list and export them into text/html/csv/xml file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, my password is already stored in the system. And it did not appear in the IE PassView. Anything else that you can suggest.

Comment: You can login with the saved information, can't you?

Comment: What does *my password is already stored in the system* mean? And Moayad is right: just hit Enter to login, and then change it...?

Comment: OK - here is the complete story. I launch IE, type http://192.168.1.1. It comes up with a screen asking for user name and password. I type the user name and password (I know the password for this screen). I click on Login. 
I see Huwaei (my modem) splash screen with the following options - Home, Setup, Advanced, Tools and Status. I choose Setup and select PVC0. Then you have got the PPP Settings displayed. This has the username, password ( I do not know this password) and few other fields. 
I would like to know this password. Hope it is clear. 
Note - I have edited the question as well.

Comment: That's a completely different thing, I've posted another answer : http://superuser.com/questions/56059/forgotten-password-to-be-unmasked-or-revealed/56103#56103

Comment: Thanks Moayad! I will check it though.

Answer (score 2):

Most routers possess a hidden Reset button that restores its state back to the default.

You can find that button in your manual, and use it to reset the router to a blank state, which will include resetting the password to the default as specified in your manual.

However, all customizations or settings that you have done in your router will be lost.

Comment: -1, that won't help here.  He knows the password for the router.  It is his ISP credentials (that the router knows, but won't reveal) that he can't remember.

Comment: @pipTheGeek: The question wasn't that clear before, and I wasn't the only one to be misled. Please ease-down on the down-voting reflex.

Comment: @pipTheGeek: That is true, it is my fault for not having written a clear question.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed after I had made my comment that the question was previously un-clear, but your answer is still not relevent, so I'm afraid the downvote stands.  After all, the point of the voting system is so that the most relevent/best answers make it to the top.

Answer (score 1):

If you can login automatically to your router (with the saved credentials), install [**ieHTTPHeaders**](http://www.blunck.se/iehttpheaders/iehttpheaders.html) and login to the router. Check in the ieHTTPHeaders panel the request where the login form was submitted. You should see the username and password in the form data.

It works even if the form is submitted to an HTTPS url.

Answer (score 1):

My modem is Linksys, rather than Huwaei, I could know the password of the PPPoE like the following:

After opening the Setup page and in my browser, I click Page => Page Source (Ctrl+U) to see the HTML source of the settings page, and from there I could find **the password as a plain text**, like that:

```
<input type="hidden" name="PppoePasswd" value="Your_Password">
```

That will work with most routers. If it doesn't, refer to [Snark's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/56059/forgotten-password-to-be-unmasked-or-revealed/56070#56070).

Comment: You're very probably right, but if this shows a dummy password then two things can cause that. 1) The provider does not require a password (but identifies the subscriber given which telephone wire is used). 2) Or the modem/router web page might include a fake password in the HTML source, just to show some stars in that password field. When clicking a "Change settings" button then, if that fake password has not been changed, it will then assume the real password should not be changed either. (And, *if* a fake password is used, then the real one cannot be found, not even using Snark's answer.)

Comment: In my case, the REAL password is shown.

Comment: Yes, I understood in your Linksys it showed the real password. And I think this is indeed the solution for the question asker as well (hence +1 without a doubt). So, my comment was just in case one finds "secret" or "customer" or "dummy" or whatever, in which case it might be fake (or irrelevant) after all.

Comment: Understand that, thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: If I do a View Source. it just shows NULL.

Comment: Did you try Snark's answer (http://superuser.com/questions/56059/forgotten-password-to-be-unmasked-or-revealed/56070#56070)? My last attempt :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, it is the password for your broadband (issued by your ISP) that you have forgotton.  If none of the tools suggested by @Arjan work easily, then I would just phone your ISP.  They will be able to tell you the password.

Out of interest, if your router is correctly configured, why do you need the password?

Comment: Good Question, out of sheer interest in knowing what I had set it as a password. Anyways, for whatever it is worth, I now have learnt a lot!

Comment: @Kanini, so have I.  My friend has a pre-configured router, the tool that Arjan mentions will be easier to get hold of the password than getting her to phone her ISP.